# Where's a Lifesaver when I need one?

Tags: support, tumbleweed-badge, winter-bash-2016

#### I've set myself to go earn [the Lifesaver hat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/lifesaver):

[image: Lifesaver badge info]

I went and posted an answer [which was accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41226016/2619939), and [here we see that that question did result in a tumbleweed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=4008366) for the OP.

Am I misunderstanding the requirement or is there something else wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: Possibilities: caching, answer may need a positive score, caching, query didn’t run (unlikely; the accept has been a few hours ago), …

Comment: You need positive score, though the hat description does not say so

Comment: I upvoted, you should receive the hat soon

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as Winter Bash 2016 has long ended, questions about it are now irrelevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## AAAAAANNNND,
<sup>here it is!</sup>

> [Your answer needs a] positive score, though the hat description does not say so
>   — @AndrewL

So, there you have it your answer needs to get an upvote in addition to being accepted.

[image: I've got the Lifesaver hat!]

### Now, please excuse me while I put it on.

Comment: Every hat involving answers has that implicit requirement.