# Winter Bash 011 hat

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

Today I got my 11th hat but I have not received the hat 011, whose requirement is to get 11 hats, I found it a bit strange since it has been a few hours since I got the 11th and I have not been given.

Are there any extra requirements for this hat? Or is it a bug? Or all the hats have to get them in the same place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the 011 hat to be awarded, all your 11 hats must be earned from the same site.

Your "The NeverEnding Story" is earned on Stack Overflow (English) as opposed to the rest. You need one more hat on Stack Overflow en español to be eligible for the hat on that site.

Comment: Really? That's weird

Comment: @PythonMaster Yea, otherwise which site should it award 011 to? ;)

Comment: @Panda Thank you very much, then the description is not very clear, because it does not specify what you are saying

Comment: @Joacer You're welcome, some descriptions do have extra criteria behind it. :)

Comment: @Panda I didn't know that,  I thought that the descriptions of the known hats on how to get them would be more detailed

Comment: @Joacer Yea, it's confusing, I remember that there's another hat that require an upvote before it's awarded though it wasn't stated

Comment: @Panda What hat ?  I would like to get more

Comment: @Joacer yea, found it, it's Lifesaver, it requires an upvote before it's awarded, here's the question, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288484/wheres-a-lifesaver-when-i-need-one

Comment: @Panda Thanks you very much, Isee that you have a lot secret hats, and i'm interested with elementary and they live, but in this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats) there is no description

Comment: @Joacer Check out this Google Doc, https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AFlWPYR7xnrQRsrVTS2Q_-sLhK7Ew1hLDz5oNKlu_n0/pub, there's the tested criteria :)

Comment: @Panda Sorry, I did not realize

Comment: @Joacer No problem, good luck on getting hats! :) You could join the chat room too should you need clarification

Comment: @panda That document I have seen, but I find it a little confusing, since there are several options and none confirmed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1064/discussion-between-panda-and-joacer).