# Can we make the 011 hat clearer?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash-2016

The description for the hat, ["011"](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/011) is not that clear:

> Collect 11 hats

Even I was confused with this. I [realized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288702/278543) that when it says collect 11 hats, it means collect 11 hats on a single site. For example, you must earn 11 hats in Stack Overflow. Its current description really says that all you need is 11 hats: regardless of which site you collected them from.

Can we change the description of the hat to:

> Collect 11 hats in one site

in order to make the description clearer and less confusing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're intentionally not thorough (there are other hat requirements not explicitly listed)

Comment: Yes, I am agree with you & I am very confuse about 011 hat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that this could be clearer, but with less than a week left of hats it's probably not going to be something we're changing for this year.

We'll keep it in mind for future years to make sure the language is better.